# Java greater than, less than comparison

Tags: java, comparison

I'm kind of confused because of my code and what to really search so please help me, I have integers they varry from 1 to the maximum amount of integers, what code should I use for example I want every integer less than 1000 to be equal to 1 and less than 2000 to be equal 2, and so on, is there an automatic comparison in java instead of doing each thousand by its own?

EDIT: I want when it is also 1000 or 2000 or what ever to be exactly as divided by without adding one, so 1000 is equal to 1, is there a way to check if there is a remainder?

Comment: How about dividing by a thousand.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is _integer division_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply need:

```
int newNum = ( num - 1 ) / 1000 + 1;
```

This gives you:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
300 -> 1
979 -> 1
1000 -> 1
1015 -> 2
1999 -> 2
2000 -> 2
2001 -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I wanted was

```
    int i = 1000;
    if (i % 1000 >0){
        i = i/1000 + 1;
    }
    else{
        i = i/1000;
    }
    System.out.print(" " + i);
```

thanks anyways for helping, I just didn't realize it was a single stupid thing

Comment: well guess u only required the path :)